# How do I select the correct hash value / Why is my hash so extremely long?

Tags: john-the-ripper

I have used `zip2john` to get the hash for a zip file like that:

```
zip2john.exe myfile.zip > hash.txt
```

john told me:

```
ver 2.0 myfile.zip/SomeDir/SomeFile.itv PKZIP Encr: cmplen=11813, decmplen=20364, crc=9CA2F026
ver 2.0 myfile.zip/packageInfo.plist PKZIP Encr: cmplen=390, decmplen=433, crc=5B49A74F

Note: It is assumed that all files in each archive have the same password. 
If that is not the case, the hash may be uncrackable. To avoid this, use option -o to pick a file at a time.
```

To do that, I have used:

```
zip2john.exe -o SomeDir/SomeFile.itv myfile.zip > hash.txt
```

Then I tried the following command to search for the pass:

```
john.exe myfile.zip hash.txt
```

john told me:

```
Warning: Invalid UTF-8 seen reading myfile.zip
Warning: detected hash type "HMAC-SHA256", but the string is also recognized as "HMAC-SHA512"
Use the "--format=HMAC-SHA512" option to force loading these as that type istead
Warning: only loading hashes of type "HMAC-SHA256", but also saw type "PKZIP"
Use the "--format=PKZIP" option to force loading hashes of that type instead.
```

I could open the zip file in 7zip, so I assumed that I should go with "PKZIP".

I am now using the following command to search for the pass:

```
john.exe myfile.zip hash.txt --format=PKZIP
```

I have opened the `hash.txt` file, and there is a huge string in it.
Its length it over 23.000 characters.

It starts with

```
myfile.zip/SomeDir/SomeFile.itv:$pkzip2$1*1*2*0*2e25*4f8c*9ca2
```

and ends with

```
(...)3366b8e749b403b58dac12fcbf73359240*$/pkzip2$:SomeDir/SomeFile.itv:myfile.zip::myfile.zip
```

Is the length of over 23.000 characters normal?

I thought hashes were rather short.

Edit:
I didn't expect that in this case, multiple hashes are involved.
Had I know this, I would have posted the entire contents of hash.txt.

The is the full contents of "hash.txt":

myfile.zip:$pkzip2$2*1*1*0*8*24*9ca2*aec6*a18a34344111501fe327f342344ca0266159d1d7771112d212fa125f22edbc14*2*0*186*1b1*5b49a74f*2e51*2f*8*186*5b49*762d*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*$/pkzip2$::myfile.zip:packageInfo.plist, SomeDir/SomeFile.itv:myfile.zip

Comment: I think the command `john.exe myfile.zip hash.txt --format=PKZIP` is wrong and the parameter `myfile.zip` isnt required

Comment: Could you provide more of the hash (maybe censor some chars with XXXX or so), also does the zip file contain multiple files?

Comment: @UndercoverDog I have re-written my post to include all the details and to understand why I did it that way.

Comment: IS this the correct syntax? `-o SomeDir/SomeFile.itv myfile.zip`

Comment: @schroeder Why do you ask? It does work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct regarding your general assumtion that hashes normally are not 23.000 characters and have a fixed length that does not depend on the input. In fact, most cryptographic hash functions are designed to take a string of any length as input and produce a fixed-length hash value.

**pkzip2 "Hash" format**

In the case of the used pkzip2 files there is a difference though. The pkzip2 files do not contain a hash of the password. It can therefore not be extracted as a hash and then cracked like one normally would.
To guess the password, zip2john extracts data and checksums from the zip file and combines that in a predefined format. That format is subject to change but currently simiar to (see "Output Line Format" in the source https://github.com/openwall/john/blob/bleeding-jumbo/src/zip2john.c#L29):

> The newer $pkzip2$ addressed the problem by adding TC (as in timestamp), but still neither zip2john
> or the format really knew when to use which (resulting in suboptimal early rejection).
> filename:$pkzip2$C*B*[DT*MT{CL*UL*CR*OF*OX}*CT*DL*CS*TC*DA]*$/pkzip2$

**Command**

The command to crack a pkzip2 file should be

```
john.exe hash.txt
```

Note that the original file must not be part of the command or else john will try to use "lines" in the file and try to detect hash formats. This results in john not beeing able to detect your hash format correctly. If you only supply the output of zip2john you will not have to specify the format manually.

**Cracking the "hash"**

The tool john then "tries a wordlist to decrypt the data stored at the DA position in zip2john's output, runs CRC32 on the result and compares that checksum with the checksum stored at the CR position".

Because the "hash" contains some of the original data, it can become quite long. The tool tries to use the smallest file in the archive to reduce the decryption work (and thereby also the length of the "hash").

This information was explained by magnum, the main contributor of the JohnTheRipper tool (https://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2021/06/03/2).

> First of all, zip2john simply picks the smallest file from the archive
> in order to minimize the work.  Sometimes there is no small file
> though.
>
> Second trick: pkzip archives also include another, smaller, checksum
> (just 1 or 2 bytes) of a tiny part of the packed data of each file.
> If  that doesn't match, we can early reject.  But if it does match
> (and  unfortunately a single byte checksum will *randomly* match in
> about 1 of  256 cases) we do have to checksum the whole (potentially
> large) file.
>
> So third trick in our bag is we collect several such smaller checksums
> (for up to 8 files), and require all of them to match before going on
> and calculate a whole-file CRC.  If the number of files is smaller, we
> may end up with less than 8 of course.  On a side note, theoretically
> the files in one archive may use different passwords and that
> invalidates this trick (in fact we'll probably get false negatives).
> That is fairly uncommon so by default we assume all have the same
> password.
>
> So best case for us is an archive with 8 or more files, and at least
> one  small file.  Worst case is an archive with only one, huge, file.

Comment: Thank you for the detailled information. Unfortunately I didn't post the entire contents of hash.txt in my question. I have added it to my question now. In fact, there seem to be 2 hashes in it. Should I just use "zip2john.exe myfile.zip > hash.txt", and then "john.exe hash.txt", and it will pick the best hash (I guess that would be the shorter one?) automatically, or do I have to do anything else?

Comment: As far as I understand, zip2john just creates one output line. If there are multiple files in the zip file, they will be listed near the end of the line (see the "packageInfo.plist, SomeDir/SomeFile.itv" in your "hash"). Could you make sure, that the two hashes are not an artifact of running the command multiple times and adding to the hash.txt file? Generally, running "zip2john.exe myfile.zip > hash.txt", and then "john.exe hash.txt" should suffice, if all files in the zip have the same password. Otherwise you would need to create specific output for files with the "-o" parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it with a new file name (hash2.txt), and it produced the same outupt, so it's not an artifact.

Comment: Could you put both lines in your initial question (redacted in the middle if you like) so I can have a look at the other fields and think about it?

Comment: It have added it to very end of my question. However, it's not 2 lines. But it's also not just the hash. The hash.txt file includes "packageInfo.plst" at the very end which is clearly not a hash. That is what I meant by 2 hashes.

Comment: In other words: Why is this string present after the hash? "::myfile.zip:packageInfo.plist, SomeDir/SomeFile.itv:myfile.zip" I am afraid that it confuses john.

Comment: Got you. The part after the "$/pkzip2$" lists the filenames that are taken into account when generating the rest of the "hash" data. They are however, as far as I can tell, not needed for the cracking process (as I just verified with a sample zip file). That is, you could delete everything after "$/pkzip2$" and the file should crack just fine (if the correct password is in your list or is guessed in a brute-force attack).

Comment: The hash file starts with "myfile.zip:" Should I delete this as well?

Comment: As far as I know you could delete it, however you can leave both the beginning and the end in the hash as they will have no bad effect on the cracking effort.